# ModuleNotFoundError in PIP package install in Conda Environment

Tags: pip, package, conda, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to install a package in a new conda environment using the pip command. It installs, but with errors, and I get `ModuleNotFoundError` in the IDE.

The steps:

`conda create --name facebookscraper python=3.8` all goes well

`conda activate facebookscraper` all goes well

`conda install pip` all goes well

`pip install facebook-scraper`
it installs, but at the end of the installation I get multiple `WARNING: Target directory /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/XYZPackageName already exists`:

```
facebookscraper) macbook@macbook ~ % pip install facebook-scraper
Collecting facebook-scraper
Using cached facebook_scraper-0.2.58-py3-none-any.whl (44 kB)
Collecting demjson3<4.0.0,>=3.0.5
Using cached demjson3-3.0.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting dateparser<2.0.0,>=1.0.0
Using cached dateparser-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (288 kB)
Collecting requests-html<0.11.0,>=0.10.0
WARNING: Target directory /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tzlocal already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
WARNING: Target directory /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dateutil already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
WARNING: Target directory /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests-2.28.1.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
WARNING: Target directory /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cssselect already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
WARNING: Target directory /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bin already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
```

When I run the following code on Visual Code Studio (using the facebookscraper conda environment as interpreter):

```
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
for post in get_posts('nintendo', pages=1):
    print(post['text'][:50])
```

I get the following `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```
[Running] python -u "/Users/macbook/Coding/python-facebook-scraper/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbook/Coding/python-facebook-scraper/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from facebook_scraper import get_posts
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'facebook_scraper'

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.11 seconds
```

I tried for force repalcement with `pip install facebook-scraper --upgrade` I get the same `ModuleNotFoundError`.

What am I doing wrong?

**P.S.**:
The reason why I am using `pip install facebook-scraper` and not `conda conda install facebook-scraper` is because the package `facebook-scraper` is not found in the conda channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip` was installing the packages by default to the `brew` directory. The solution was to tell `pip` to install in the `site-packages` directory of the virtual environment. This is what solved the problem:

`python -m pip install --target=/Users/macbook/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages facebook-scraper`

Comment: This is only shadowing the actual problem. The `pip` that belongs to the `conda` env should also install to the conda env by default.

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is installing to `/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9` which is not te path of a conda environment, but of a python3.9 installed using `brew`. Maybe you have an alias defined for `pip`? You can check by running `type pip`

Check that `python` calls the interpreter from your environment and then do

```
 python -m pip install facebook-scraper
```

Comment: Thank you. It did work with `python -m pip install facebook-scraper`. 
I tried to execute the script, and had the same `ModuleNotFoundError` with demjson3 I tried with `conda install demjson3` it installed, but script throws `ModuleNotFoundError` and `python -m pip instal demjson3` installs, but `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: Please accept the answer then to mark the question as resolved

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: Now tried with another `pip install package` and another environment, same issue... 
I am running from Visual Studio or from the terminal, I get the `ModuleNotFoundError`

Comment: The problem is that `pip` is installing packages in `/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages`
I am using `python -m pip install package` from any `conda` virtual environment 
`type pip` shows `/Users/macbook/opt/conda3/envs/facebookscraper/bin/pip`
`which python` shows `/Users/macbook/opt/conda3/envs/facebookscraper/bin/python`
Any thoughts?

Comment: Some global pip config file or the environment variable `PIP_TARGET` set to override the target path?